# MySQL insert JSON data type in existing row

Tags: mysql, json

I have a column in my MySQL table that is type json. I am trying to update a row with a SQL script.

This is the JSON I am attempting to insert into the column

```
{
  "HE": [{
    "isbn": "1234",
    "type": "Some text"
  }],
  "HS": []
}
```

I have tried quite a few different ways with no luck, below is the method of updating a row I am most familiar with.

```
UPDATE `textbooks` 
SET `isbns` = {"HE":[{"isbn":"9781337763639","type":"Single Term HW & 
eBook University"}],"HS":[]} 
WHERE `id` = 939;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON string has to be in quotes. Also, it shouldn't have newlines in it.

```
UPDATE `textbooks` 
SET `isbns` = '{"HE":[{"isbn":"9781337763639","type":"Single Term HW & eBook University"}],"HS":[]}'
WHERE `id` = 939;
```

Comment: question in similar context,

what if I would like to set isbn=id+something. In that case, how can I set any field in the json with variable params?

Comment: See the functions for modifying JSON values [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html)